# Calling A Handler From An Integration Test

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I know I'm having the most exotic use cases ever, but I really like tests, and so I would like to test if a `IHandler` works the way I assume it should. The problem is I can't figure out how to call it programmatically:

```
IWorkbenchPage workbenchPage = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage()
IWorkbenchWindow site = workbenchPage.getWorkbenchWindow();
Command command = ((ICommandService) site.getService(ICommandService.class)).getCommand(commandId);

final IHandlerService service = (IHandlerService) site.getService(IHandlerService.class);
final Event trigger = new Event(); // or trigger = null
ExecutionEvent executionEvent = service.createExecutionEvent(command, trigger);
command.executeWithChecks(executionEvent);
```

The handler gets called, but the `ExecutionEvent` is not filled correctly (e.g. `HandlerUtil.getActiveEditor(ExecutionEvent)` returns null even though I just opened an editor).

How do I call a `IHandler` programmatically the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also do like tests a lot :-) However, I usually *manually* equip the evaluation context with those variables that are required for the handler to execute.

For example:

```
EvaluationContext context = new EvaluationContext( null, new Object() )
context.addVariable( ISources.ACTIVE_PART_NAME, activePart );
context.addVariable( ISources.ACTIVE_CURRENT_SELECTION_NAME, selection );
// add whatever is used by the handler...

Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
ExecutionEvent event = new ExecutionEvent( command, parameters, null, context );

command.executeWithChecks( event );
```

Let me know if this approach is viable for you. Otherwise, I may be able to dig out how to get hold of the *real* evaluation context of my test helper code.

Comment: You can evidently get the `IEvaluationContext` from `IHandlerService.getCurrentState()`... or at least now my tests work.